# Cargar alerta de la vista parcial en la vista principal

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Tengo dos vistas una principal que sería **Home** y una parcial **Proceso** que se carga dentro de la principal. Lo que intento hacer es mostrar una alerta después de una solicitud post que realiza la vista parcial de esta manera:

> Controlador de la vista parcial

```
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    public class ProcesoController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string item)
        {
            if (item!= null){  //proceso }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.AlertPartial = "Mensaje";
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

> Vista parcial

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index","Proceso")">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" name="item" value="1">Item
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Procesar</button>
    </div>
    @if (ViewBag.AlertPartial != null)
    {
       <strong>Aviso!</strong> @ViewBag.AlertPartial
    }
</form>
```

Funciona pero se abre en otra pestaña la vista parcial con la alerta y quisiera que se abra la alerta en la misma página junto a la principal.

> Controlador de la vista principal

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

> Vista principal

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
    <br /><h2>Etiquetas...</h2><br />
</form>

@Html.Action("Index", "Proceso")
```

> Captura

[image: inicio]

[image: proceso]

Comment: Lo mejor es que con javascript manejes ocultar o mostrar el mensaje.